# Why doesn't this thread ever end?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sequence

I'm trying to control a piece of test equipment and I need to get the sequencing correct of how I communicate with it.

First I call `StartGettingTraceData()`. Then some time in the future I call `StopGettingTraceData()` to attempt to end the `GetTraceData()` function instead of it re-launching itself. But that NEVER happens. In fact, I never get to the line `DoneTraces.Set()` so on the line `bool timedOut = !DoneTraces.WaitOne(10000)`, `timedOut` always is true;

```
private static AutoResetEvent DoneTraces = new AutoResetEvent(false);

private void GetTraceData()
{
    byte[] receivedbytes = new byte[1];
    if (Connection.ReadData(receivedbytes) && receivedbytes[0] == 192)
        ProcessIncomingTrace();

    Thread.Sleep(100);

    if (RunTraceQueryWorker)
        new Thread(GetTraceData).Start();
    else
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        DoneTraces.Set();
    }
}

private void StartGettingTraceData()
{
    RunTraceQueryWorker = true;
    new Thread(GetTraceData).Start();
}

private bool StopGettingTraceData()
{
    RunTraceQueryWorker = false;
    bool timedOut = !DoneTraces.WaitOne(10000);
    return timedOut;
}
```

Any thoughts on what is going on?

**EDIT:**

Here is my Connection.ReadData(...) function. It's a serial connection by the way.

```
public bool ReadData(byte[] responseBytes)
{
    int bytesExpected = responseBytes.Length, offset = 0, bytesRead;
    while (bytesExpected > 0 && (bytesRead = MySerialPort.Read(responseBytes, offset, bytesExpected)) > 0)
    {
        offset += bytesRead;
        bytesExpected -= bytesRead;
    }
    return bytesExpected == 0;
}
```

Comment: Threads are expensive so you shouldn't create them recursively. Having so many threads (doing `Sleep()` ) is probably also your not-stopping problem.

Comment: Have you tried using the DataReceived Event handler?  I looked at the manual last night and it seems pretty straight forward, except for the different responses that are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than recusively calling GetTraceData again, you should use a while loop looking at your condition like this:

```
private static AutoResetEvent DoneTraces = new AutoResetEvent(false);

private void GetTraceData()
{
    do
{
    byte[] receivedbytes = new byte[1];
    if (Connection.ReadData(receivedbytes) && receivedbytes[0] == 192)
        ProcessIncomingTrace();

    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
while (RunTraceQueryWorker)

Thread.Sleep(200);
DoneTraces.Set();

}

private void StartGettingTraceData()
{
    RunTraceQueryWorker = true;
    new Thread(GetTraceData).Start();
}

private bool StopGettingTraceData()
{
    RunTraceQueryWorker = false;
    bool timedOut = !DoneTraces.WaitOne(10000);
    return timedOut;
}
```

It's impossible to know specifically why your code is freezing without understanding what `ReadData` & `ProcessIncomingTrace()` do.

Comment: You are right. Things work fine when I comment out those two lines of code. I must have other problems.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint int the ReadData() call, do you ever see it return?

Comment: I decided to use code very similar to yours (do while loop). Do solve my problem I had to thread the `ProcessIncomingTrace()` function. Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, chances are that the `ReadData` call is blocking.  As an aside, you're making it hard on yourself with all this recursive threading...  Can't you just use a loop?

```
private void GetTraceData()
{
    byte[] receivedbytes = new byte[1];

    while( RunTraceQueryWorker )
    {
        if( Connection.ReadData(receivedbytes) && receivedbytes[0] == 192 )
        {
            ProcessIncomingTrace();
        }
        Sleep(100);
    }

    Thread.Sleep(200);
    DoneTraces.Set();
}
```